# How to find different types of file from a path

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, avatar

A user avatar is saved in `../wordpress/wp-content/uploads/` folder with name and extension as that of input. That is,  If a PNG file is uploaded, the extension becomes `user_avatar0.png`, otherwise if JPG is uploaded it will becomes `user_avatar0.jpg`. 
I am loading multiple user avatars using for each loop.

This is the code I have used to load avatar file :

```
$path="../wordpress/wp-content/uploads/";
$av=$path."user_avatar0.png|.jpg"; // if jpg exists loads jpg otherwise load png
<img src="'. $av .'"   height="200" width="200" border="0" >
```

How to select a file from a directory, that contains files of different extensions(jpg, png etc.) ?

Comment: A file with a mulitple extensions could be something like: `file.en.html`.  Which is valid, but probably not what you mean here.

Answer (score 1):

What you have attempted with the clever `.png|.jpg` is unfortunately not a known syntax. It won't be interpreted by either PHP or the browser that parses the HTML. PHP doesn't have a feature that'd auto-fill path variables in way of shell parameter expansion [<sup>?</sup>](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) . There's of course [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.glob.php), but globbing the whole directory to get a single file with either jpg/png extension would be very inefficient.

If you have no record of what the file extension is (you could query your WP database?), you'll have to simply check with something like this, presuming jpg/png are the only possibilities:

```
$file = 'user_avatar0.';
$file .= file_exists($file.'jpg') ? 'jpg' : 'png';
```

This concatenates the basename with a `jpg` extension if there's a match, and falls back to `png` if not. If there's a chance the user has no avatar at all, then you should do `if-elseif-else` instead, and default to a standard placeholder if both `file_exists` checks fail. You could also use [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php), [`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) or [`stream_resolve_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-resolve-include-path.php) to verify if a file exists; but the logic remains the same. Rumor goes the last option would be the fastest, but in any case each of them caches its results.

Regardless, if you keep displaying the same users' avatars on recurring page-loads, you'll want to consider saving the results of these checks into a `$_SESSION` array to eliminate repeated and redundant checking. I'll leave it to you to benchmark PHP's filesys cache vs. session cache.

Comment: In related functions, there's `fnmatch()` ~ http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php ~ that can be used to check if a file matching a regex pattern exists. However it only returns a boolean so it's not helpful in OP's case. Just for the record re: parallels to shell patterns in PHP.

Comment: any syntax errors in this line, if any?  `$file .= file_exists($file.'jpg') ? 'jpg : 'png'; `

Comment: Unclosed quote after `'jpg`. Now fixed in the post.